# how to return internal structure from template class

Tags: c++, templates, struct

My question is as the title?
how to return internal structure from template class?

```
template<class TYPE3>
class MyClass
{
public:

    typedef struct MyNode_type {
        int Key;
        TYPE3 Data;
    }MyNode;

private:

    MyNode *m_Root;

    //=== My Question is Here =====/
    MyClass<TYPE3>::MyNode *getRootNode() {
        return m_Root;
    }

};
```

i want to return m_Root from getRootNode function but i don't know how to define its type
so i can use like:
MyClass::MyNode *rootnode = cls.getRootNode();

Thank you for the help! ..

Answer (score 2):

When you do `MyClass<int>::MyNode` that would correctly resolve to the internal structure type. However, when you do `MyClass<TYPE3>::MyNode` where `TYPE3` is a template parameter you need to let the compiler know that you are referring to a type by inserting `typename`:

```
typename MyClass<TYPE3>::MyNode* getRootNode() ...
```

Also, lose that `typedef struct`, this is C++ not C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use typdefs

in your template:

```
typedef typename MyClass<TYPE3>::MyNode NodeType;
```

elsewhere:

```
MyClass<TYPE3>::NodeType* pNode = cls.getRootNode();
```